# Microsoft Graph Planner API missing recurring tasks in response

Tags: microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I'm programming an application for Microsoft Planner and I need to get the tasks of individual users. I am using Microsoft Graph Planner API. However, there are no recurring tasks in response. Recurring events are present in the internal api planner, the specific call is :

`https://tasks.office.com/{clientID}/TasksApiV1/GetPlanDataAsync?planId={planId}`.

I am unable to authenticate. I'm using TeamsFxProvider for authentication, but the token with the api https://tasks.office.com doesn't work (bad credentials error). Is there a way around this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tasks.office.com is not a supported API you can use. It exists just to provide the web experience and will change frequently without notice. We're working on enabling the recurring tasks in the Graph API, which should be available soon.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Recurring Tasks is now available via the Graph beta endpoint!

Documentation for the feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/planner-task-recurrence-overview